# Proper way to write a C++17 style "_v" helper template for a nested template

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, type-traits

The standard library provides templates to determine different type traits at compile time. For example:

`std::is_integral<T>::value` will tell you whether something is an integral type or not.

Since C++17, shortcut "helper templates" were added for these type trait templates.

`std::is_integral_v<T>` provides the same result without requiring `::value`

---

Similar to `std::is_integral`, I have a relatively complicated template to determine whether one type is a specialization of another:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Template>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> typename Template, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};
```

A usage example is shown below (This will enable this template function if the type passed in is a specialization of `std::complex`):

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct MyComplex
{
    MyComplex(const T& real, const T& imag)
        : real(real)
        , imag(imag)
    {}

    T real() { return this->real; }

    T imag() { return this->imag; }

private:
    T real;
    T imag;
};

// Only enable this template if "T" is a specialization of "std::complex"
template <typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<is_specialization<T, std::complex>::value>
>
void foo(T value)
{
    std::cout << value.real() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> value1{ 1.0, 2.0 };
    foo(value1);

    std::complex<int> value2{ 1, 2 };
    foo(value2);

    MyComplex<double> value3{ 1.0, 2.0 };

    // Fails to compile because "MyComplex<double>" is not a specialization of "std::complex"
    //foo(value3);
}
```

---

I would like to write an "_v" helper template for this, but I'm unsure how since it involves nested templates.

Since `is_specialization` takes two template parameters, my first thought was to just do something like this and maybe the compiler would figure out that "T" and "U" can be nested types on its own, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_v = is_specialization<T, U>::value;
```

What is the correct way to write an "_v" helper template for something like this? Please also try to explain how it works in the answer since I am fairly new to template meta-programming and I am still struggling with some of the concepts.

Comment: is that example real code? Does not compile here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2bewoB73d17BrjCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument of alias is wrong, it should be the same as primary template:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Template>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_v = is_specialization<T, Template>::value;
```

Comment: Ahh i see, I guess that makes sense, but why the same as the primary template? Why don't I need a "helper" template for the secondary one as well?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 For all practical purposes, specializations don't exist.  What they are is a recipe that says if you get these template parameters, stamp out the template this way instead.  When you interact with the template, you only interact with the primary because of this.

Comment: You might still after have specialization of your alias. but here, all the "hard" part is done with `is_specialization`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for being so helpful over the past couple days! I think I'm almost done sorting this whole thing out, but I'm still having issues with one last thing. I'm going to Google around for a bit but I may have one more question coming haha.